# How to break a line in centered flexbox div container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to align a div element vertically and horizontally. I did that using flex display, but now the elements are displayed in a single line even though `<br>` is present. How can I separate the paragraph and image elements into two lines?

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div style="width:100%; height:100%; color:#fff; background-color:black;" class="center">
    <p>SOME TEXT</p>
    <br>
    <img style="max-height:100%; max-width:100%;" src="http://www.jacobsladderky.com/uploads/6/9/1/4/69146851/4652558.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: and what is the need of flex here ? text-align:center will be enough

Comment: text-align: center wasn't enough because I needed the container to be centered not only horizontally but vertically as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can use `flex-direction: column;` property to align element in 1
>   column, see this [flexbox documentation](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div style="width:100%; height:100%; color:#fff; background-color:black;" class="center">
    <p>SOME TEXT</p>
    <img style="max-height:100%; max-width:100%;" src="http://www.jacobsladderky.com/uploads/6/9/1/4/69146851/4652558.png" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="width: 100%;height: 100%;color: #fff;background-color: black;text-align:  center;" class="center" data-mce-style="width: 100%; height: 100%; color: #fff; background-color: black;"><p>SOME TEXT</p><br> <img style="max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%;" src="http://www.jacobsladderky.com/uploads/6/9/1/4/69146851/4652558.png" data-mce-src="http://www.jacobsladderky.com/uploads/6/9/1/4/69146851/4652558.png" data-mce-style="max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%;"></div>
```

JUST CHANGE THIS DIV